# how to pass tag name to the tidy custom-tags option

Tags: tidy

I try to indent an HTML file with tidy, the HTML file has with "non HTML" tags starting by `pin-`.

You can got it with:

```bash
$ URL="https://policy.pinterest.com/en/digital-services-act-transparency-report"
$ curl -s $URL > dsatr.html
```

The starting `pin-` tags:

```xml
$ grep "pin-" dsatr.html -c
300
$ grep "pin-" dsatr.html |head -2
  <pin-header
</pin-header>
```

tidy in HTML mode (the default) can not clean/indent this HTML because of this pin
tags (output recommend to use custom-tags):

```bash
$ tidy -o out.html dsatr.html
line 46 column 3 - Error: <pin-header> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 66 column 7 - Error: <pin-page-header> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 74 column 7 - Error: <pin-paragraph> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 84 column 5 - Error: <pin-grid> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 95 column 15 - Error: <pin-heading> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
$
```

With `custom-tags` we get no better results

```bash
$ cat ct.txt
custom-tags=pin-header,pin-page-header,pin-paragraph,pin-grid,pin-heading
$ tidy --config ct.txt -o out.html dsatr.html
custom-tags=pin-header,pin-page-header,pin-paragraph,pin-grid,pin-heading
line 46 column 3 - Error: <pin-header> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 66 column 7 - Error: <pin-page-header> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 74 column 7 - Error: <pin-paragraph> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 84 column 5 - Error: <pin-grid> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 95 column 15 - Error: <pin-heading> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
$
```

Neither with `new-blocklevel-tags`:

```bash
$ cat nbt.txt 
new-blocklevel-tag=pin-header,pin-page-header,pin-paragraph,pin-grid,pin-heading
$ tidy --config nbt.txt -o out.html dsatr.html 
new-blocklevel-tag=pin-header,pin-page-header,pin-paragraph,pin-grid,pin-heading
line 46 column 3 - Error: <pin-header> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 66 column 7 - Error: <pin-page-header> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 74 column 7 - Error: <pin-paragraph> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 84 column 5 - Error: <pin-grid> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
line 95 column 15 - Error: <pin-heading> is not recognized! Did you mean to enable the custom-tags option?
$
```

On the official documentation no way to find a working example of `custom-tags`.

```
$ tidy -help-option custom-tags

`--custom-tags`

This option enables the use of tags for autonomous custom elements, e.g.      
<flag-icon> with Tidy. Custom tags are disabled if this value is no. 
Other settings - blocklevel, empty, inline, and pre will treat all    
detected custom tags accordingly.                                             
                                                                              
The use of new-blocklevel-tags, new-empty-tags,             
new-inline-tags, or new-pre-tags will override the treatment
of custom tags by this configuration option. This may be useful if you have   
different types of custom tags.                                               
                                                                              
When enabled these tags are determined during the processing of your document 
using opening tags; matching closing tags will be recognized accordingly, and 
unknown closing tags will be discarded.
$
```

Comment: Still not an expert, but you're helping me improve (-;! .. Note the doc says *"Custom tags are disabled if this value is no."*, Reread the section https://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.6.0.html#custom-tags and note especially the `See also` links (`new-blocklevel-tags, new-empty-tags, new-inline-tags, new-pre-tags`). You'll need to read each of these and decide which apply to your situation. (possibly thru more experimentation). Note that `new-blocklevel-tags` help says **"his option takes a space or comma separated list of tag names."**.  Good luck.

Comment: Question edited to provide the HTML data exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the values suggested in the help text.  I'm not sure if other values are supported, at least on v5.7.45 that I'm getting from my package manager.

For example

```
$ URL="https://policy.pinterest.com/en/digital-services-act-transparency-report"
$ curl -s $URL > dsatr.html
$ tidy --custom-tags blocklevel dsatr.html
```

At the head of the output you'll see that it's interpreting the tags as `block level` elements.

```
line 46 column 3 - Info: detected autonomous custom tag <pin-header>; will treat as block level
line 66 column 7 - Info: detected autonomous custom tag <pin-page-header>; will treat as block level
line 74 column 7 - Info: detected autonomous custom tag <pin-paragraph>; will treat as block level
line 84 column 5 - Info: detected autonomous custom tag <pin-grid>; will treat as block level
line 95 column 15 - Info: detected autonomous custom tag <pin-heading>; will treat as block level
line 158 column 141 - Info: detected autonomous custom tag <pin-link>; will treat as block level
```